# Is it better for your character model to be filled or hollow inside?

Tags: modeling

I'm making a character model that will be rigged and used for a 3D animation I'm making for class. In tutorials I see, they keep their models hollow. Is it better to keep your model hollow? Will my model still be ok if it's filled inside while rigging or will there be problems I'll encounter?

Comment: What is "filled" object? Could you show some comparison?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hollow and if I'm correct you can not fill your model it's just not possible.
And even if you fill your model it will be very expensive as it will drastically increase poly count making you animation worse and also punish your hardware.

Answer (score 0):

All 3D character models are hollow inside,there is no such thing as filled model.

Comment: This isn't an absolute truth. You can have volumetrically-defined models such as metaballs. Even though they are rendered as "hollow" when you place the viewport camera inside them, they are defined as a volume and thus "filled".

Comment: Yeah you are right.